# Android Studio - How to stop all modules from building everything?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a main project with many module dependencies. This project has many build variants.  Some of the modules have tests, too.

The problem is that it is executing the tasks for *everything*, rather than on the command line where I can select one thing with gradle.

How do I make just one task build in Android Studio for this project?  It's especially problematic for fresh checkouts or clean builds.

Comment: When you sync AS with Gradle it executes tasks which generate resources (such as R.java file). That's hardly everything. What's this **everything**? **When** is it executing? What **one thing** in command line? Be concrete when asking for help.

Comment: Everything - all of the modules in the workspace.  When - fresh checkout or clean build.  In other words, all the modules get auto imported, and then they're all built all at once, even if they're not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's Gradle pane in Android Studio which (after syncing with Gradle) allows you to ad hoc execute individual tasks.

[image: Gradle tab]

Comment: Neat! That got me part way! I ignored the gradle tasks I didn't want.  Except they all got removed from the project structure.

Comment: Try looking into main menu > Run > Edit Configurations... if you need something very much custom besides executing a single gradle task or running an app module.

Comment: I've been looking at that all day. :/ It's more that I want the modules to show up in IntelliJ, but the gradle actions to not execute (only execute as direct dependency of build).